# How can I make Spring Data Couchbase persist the id field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm just starting a new project using CouchBase 4.5 and Spring Data CouchBase.  I have an entity that looks like this:

```
@Document
public class ItemType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -874553420214538944L;

    @Id
    @Field
    private String key;

    @Field
    private String displayName;

    @Field
    private int appAccountId;

    @Field
    private Map<String, FieldType> fieldTypes;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public int getAppAccountId() {
        return appAccountId;
    }

    public void setAppAccountId(int appAccountId) {
        this.appAccountId = appAccountId;
    }

    public Map<String, FieldType> getFieldTypes() {
        return fieldTypes;
    }

    public void setFieldTypes(Map<String, FieldType> fieldTypes) {
        this.fieldTypes = fieldTypes;
    }
}
```

When I save it using the CouchBase CrudRepository, it winds up like this in the DB:

```
{
  "_class": "com.mycompany.models.ItemType",
  "appAccountId": 2,
  "displayName": "Image - External",
  "fieldTypes": {
    "location": {
      "rank": 1,
      "type": "String",
      "publishCascade": false,
      "displayName": "Location",
      "displayAttributes": {
        "uiDisplayType": "TEXT_FIELD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything seems fine except the "key" field is not persisted in the document.  I've tried it both with and without the @Field annotation, but the result is the same.  Is there any way I can make sure the @Id fields are persisted to the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Data Couchbase implementation uses the `@Id` field as the document key in Couchbase. It then ignores that particular field during persistence, and `@Field` doesn't change that.

Not ignoring `@Field` in this particular case would complicate the deserialization logic, since the value of 1 attribute would be in 2 places...

Comment: so how will we add the references of independent documents into our current document?

Comment: @Simon so what if my business requirement is that the id property (annotated with @Id) is required to exist in the document, rather than as meta data on the document?

Comment: @Jared, did you get solution for this. I am also facing this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You may be hitting a reserved word?

If you change "key" to anything else like "keyz" does it work?

I do see that KEY is a reserved word in N1QL -

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/reservedwords.html

Comment: Darn I really thought this was the answer!  Unfortunately, I tried several other field names like keyz and id, but they don't show up either.

Comment: You can escape reserved words with back ticks.